# How to replace text defined in a given tag or element using xslt, xslt string replace

Tags: string, xslt, replace

Please help me with this xslt transformation.

Source Xml

```
<xml>
 <test>This is a <bold>sample</bold> description. Please help me with a sample</text>
</xml>
```

Expected Output: This is a **sample** description. Please help me with a sample

I just need to make bold only the specified text by the xml markup.

Thank you

Comment: what do you want for your output format ? html ? rtf ? ps ? ...

Comment: Good Question (+1). See my answer for a complete solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="text">
   <p>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </p>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="bold">
   <b><xsl:apply-templates/></b>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied against the provided XML document**:

```
<xml>
 <text>This is a <bold>sample</bold> description. Please help me with a sample</text>
</xml>
```

**produces the desired result in HTML**:

```
 <p>This is a <b>sample</b> description. Please help me with a sample</p>
```

Comment: @m00sila: Glad it works. In such cases you are expected to accept the answer (click on the check mark that must be displayed somewhere near the answer). :)